# What is the group generated by the union of two dihedral groups?

Tags: group-theory

What can be said about the group generated by the union of the two dihedral group $D_n$ and $D_m$, for all natural numbers $n, m$? Is it $D_{lcm(n,m)}$? After some heuristics it does seem to me the union of the isometries of the rectangle and that of the square yields the isometries of the dodecagon.

Thanks

Edit: the dihedral groups are seen as sub groups of $O(2,R)$

Comment: Generated how? Within some larger group?

Comment: You need to be specific -- you can't just take the 'union of groups.' You can join them if they are subgroups of a third group, but *how* they are subgroups affects the outcome.

Comment: What does $D_n$ mean to you, exactly? (Not everyone uses the same notation for dihedral groups.) What are the isometries of the square and rectangle, what is their "union", and how is it related to the isometries of the dodecagon? I'm sure you're not claiming that $4\times8=24$, so I must be misunderstanding something you wrote. If you actually showed your work it might be easier to understand.

Comment: I get you consider all the dihedral groups as subgroups of $O(2,\Bbb R)$. Is it true? Or are you considering them as subgroups of $S_{\Bbb N}$ through the natural maps $D_n\hookrightarrow S_{n}\hookrightarrow S_{\Bbb N}$ ?

Comment: Oh, sorry for that! I'm French so I tried to keep it light for fear of bad notations... My constructive definition of the group generated by D_ and D_m would be the group of the form {σ_1^k_1...σ_2n+2m^k_2n+2m | σ_i in D_m or D_n and k in A}, so no need for a larger group containing D_n and D_m, right? Otherwise yes O(2,R) would be satisfactory I guess. My definition of D_n : D_n is the group (of cardinal 2n) of isometries preserving the n-sided regular polygon. Also, isn't a dodecagon 12-sided? Edit: Sorry for the lack of latex, I'm on my phone and just getting used to this forum.

Comment: What I did with D_3 and D_4: I considered only the rotations (not the symmetries), made the assumption that the union of both groups does yield a dihedral group of higher order and came to the conclusion with some substractions (2/3-1/2) that if it does it must have π/6 as the angle of its smallest (in angle) rotation, so I concluded it must be D_12. So, pretty heuristic! Edit: in my previous comment, in the definition of the group generated by D_n and D_m, I meant  Z and not "A".

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it's clear.  Users shouldn't have to read a bunch of comments to understand what the question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subgroup of $O(2)$ generated by $D_n$ and $D_m$, regarded as subgroups of $O(2)$ in the usual way, is $D_{\text{lcm}(m, n)}$.

But it's important to note that when people say "$D_n$" by default they mean $D_n$ as an abstract group, independent of any particular embedding into a larger group such as $O(2)$. In that setting there's no meaningful way to take the "union" of two groups. There is a meaningful [coproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct), but it's usually very large.

Comment: @Raphael: I don't know, but it's not a very difficult exercise to just do.